# Vertical to Horizontal Transpose in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, transpose

```
Sub transposeVBAS()

Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C2:C12").Copy
Sheets("sheet2").Range("B2").PasteSpecial Transpose:=True

End Sub
```

I'm facing problem going to next cell for other entries once the transpose is successful.

I know I have got similar question from past, but those codes seems be very big.

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: Not sure I understand what you need... What 'next cell for other entries' would mean? "C13" in "Sheet1" and B3 in "Sheet2"? Range "D2:D12" in "Sheet1"? Please try to better define your need in order to receive some help...

Comment: Sorry for no clarity.
The code is able to transpose vertical entries to B2:L2
But when i enter new data into the vertical format, the new data overrides the old data (on B2:L2).

The help here is that, the data should be transposed to B3:L3 , 
B4:L4 
B5:L5 and so on.

Comment: Then you can [find the last row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11169445/error-in-finding-last-used-cell-in-excel-with-vba) and write to the next available one.

Comment: Understood where to paste the transposed values, but would you all the time copy data from the range `Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C2:C12")`?

Comment: @FaneDuru Yes Sir, copying data will always be same from same location in this scenario.

Comment: It will be a little strange, on my  taste... So, would you like a loop to all the time copy the same vertical range from the first sheet and transpose it on rows of the second sheet?  And where to stop the loop for the second sheet range? On B12?

Comment: @FaneDuru No Sir, Nothing like B12 here , that would totally depend on the data i feed into the vertical column.
It is possible without a loop ?
If no, how would you do it ?

Comment: So, your "C12" is only an example? Would you like to copy all existing values on the vertical range?

Comment: Yes, i would like to transpose all the data from C2:C12 in Sheet 1   to 
B2:L2 in Sheet 2.

That's the idea, but thanks a lot sir for your valuable inputs, questions asked by you  were helpful too.
Got the answer from @BigBen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're just trying to paste to the next available row:

```
With Sheets("sheet2")
    .Cells(.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).offset(1).PasteSpecial Transpose:=True
End With
```

Comment: Sir, thanks a lot.
I get bugged up with this End(X1Up) and similar syntax.

Comment: `xlUp` - it's the letter `l` as in `leprechaun`, not the number `1`.